# why wrong name with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception

I created a `List.java` file in folder `UtilityPack` which contains this code

```
package Utilities;
public class List
{
    private class node{}
    public void insert(int data){}
    public void print(){}
    public static void main(String[] s){}
}
```

To compile i did

```
C:\UtilityPack>javac List.java
```

But when I try to run with

```
C:\UtilityPack>java -classpath . List
```

OR

```
C:\UtilityPack>java List
```

I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: List (wrong name: Uti
lities/List)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I have been trying to **execute** this program from last 3 hours but nothing worked..please help

Comment: If you compile it with `javac -d . List.java` then the compiler will automatically put the class file in the right place (namely `C:\UtilityPack\Utilities\List.class`).

Comment: It's a simple rule -- you can get around it with difficulty -- but ALWAYS place source/classes in the directories that correspond to their package names, and put the "root" directories (directories where those package-named directories are found) in your class path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the fully qualified name e.g.

```
java -cp . Utilities.List
```

i.e. you're telling the JVM to look from the current direct (`-cp .`) for a class `Utilities.List`, which it will expect in the file `Utilities\List.class`.

To be more consistent you should put the .java file under a `Utilities` directory (yes - this is tautologous - the package specifies this, but it's consistent practise).

I would also avoid calling your class `List`. At some stage you're going to import a `java.util.List` and it'll all get very confusing!

Finally, as soon as you get more than a couple of classes, investigate [ant](http://ant.apache.org) or another build tool, and separate your `source` and `target` directories.

Comment: omg..this is so confusing..solved the problem by creating the folder `Utilities`...thank you so much...

Comment: It *is* confusing. Basically you need the directory structure to mirror the package structure so it's consistent, although Java doesn't *require* that.

Comment: do i always need to create directory if i specify any package..so for package name like `A1.A2` do i need to create 2 directories A2 under A1 **always**

Comment: also do i need to create directory if i dont specify any package

Comment: @cSharper the directory structure for `.class` files must match their packages. The `javac` compiler doesn't necessarily require the same of `.java` sources, but pretty much every higher-level build tool prefers it that way, including Ant, Maven, and IDEs.

Comment: @IanRoberts :)..thx for that info...i am a beginner so i have another doubt..do we have to create separate file for each public class..

Comment: @cSharper a `.java` file can contain at most one `public class` and the name of this class must match the file name, the file can contain other non-public classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete name of the class to lauch your program :

```
 java Utilities.List
```

But the folder name should also match the package name.

Comment: i tried it but it gives this error `Error: Could not find or load main class Utilities.List`

Comment: You should make the folder named like the directory, and then point the classpath to the parent directory.

Comment: omg..this is so confusing..solved the problem by creating the folder `Utilities`...thank you so much...

Comment: do i always need to create directory if i specify any package..so for package name like `A1.A2` do i need to create 2 directories A2 under A1 **always**..also do i need to create directory if i dont specify any package

Comment: Yes. That's a basic rule. You'll see it helps manage your files as they grow in number. Many java programs are made of thousand of classes.

Comment: :)..thx...i am a beginner so i have another doubt..do we have to create separate file for each public class..and if it is what does that achieve

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure needs to follow your Java package pathing. IOW, if the class `List`is in the package `Utilities`, you need to situate it in a directory called Utilities, which should be at the root level of your project, i.e. the path of the source file should be **C:\UtilityPack\Utilities\List.java**. When you are in **C:\UtilityPack** (project root), you compile and run `List` by referencing it as `Utilities.List`.

You might also consider using Eclipse, it will prevent this sort of things from happening, or any other Java IDE.

Comment: do i always need to create directory if i specify any package..so for package name like `A1.A2` do i need to create 2 directories A2 under A1 **always**

Comment: @cSharper - Yes -- ALWAYS make the directory structure match the package name structure.